# jquery Scroll Event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem on my website and i don't know why my code is not working on mobile. i used a lot of function like touchmove, onscroll   but still not working. im Jquery beginner.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 325) {
    $(".ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before").addClass("ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after");
  } else {
    $(".ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before").removeClass("ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after");
  }
});
```

```css
*.ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

*.ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after {
  position: fixed;
  top: 46px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before">
  <div class="test1">
    Scroll Test Drive
  </div>
</div>
```

and it is possible to have a code that make the scroll event not work on the whole site?

Comment: Just FYI, your CSS classes don't need the `*` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the Info.  Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposal for what you need (i just changed slightly your Y-offset values to adapt this example to the code snippet frame):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (st > 100) {
      $(".ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before").addClass("ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after");
    } else {
      $(".ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before").removeClass("ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1009;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.ONE-DAY-HAWAII-after {
  position: fixed;
  top: 46px;
  z-index: 1009;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

      <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="ONE-DAY-HAWAII-before">
        <div class="test1">
          Scroll Test Drive
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>Proin at dolor leo. Duis id vehicula tellus. Donec ornare tincidunt dui sed placerat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>Aenean vel felis volutpat, euismod enim vel, vestibulum justo. Donec accumsan nulla id est faucibus sagittis. Nunc hendrerit finibus sollicitudin. Duis in vestibulum odio. Nulla aliquam, orci sit amet facilisis scelerisque, libero odio vestibulum
          libero, quis imperdiet justo leo sit amet felis. Nam a risus convallis tellus consectetur efficitur a ac erat. Integer eu magna dignissim, luctus ipsum eget, posuere diam. Mauris tellus nibh, fringilla nec pulvinar vitae, accumsan venenatis
          nulla. Maecenas nec lacinia sapien. Proin nec lacus leo. Ut tincidunt ante in nisi vehicula commodo. Mauris vel elit blandit, molestie velit sed, placerat justo. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Feel free to test it on your mobile device and ask again if you need some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this deblocker. can i ask one question? it is possible to have a code that make the scroll event not work on the whole site? like some outsource code? thanks again \m/

Comment: @HariNgNepal: just with these two lines, you question sounds somewhat vague... kindly post a new question for that, and provide as much information as possible to get further assistance. Write down exactly what you are actually doing and define clearly what is your goal.